# How to create json dinamically nesting info inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I'm developing a code to analyse image pixels (totally 1,048,576 for each image). As it's going to be a huge amount of info to insert on a database I decided that the best option may be to create a file to store all results.

So on, I'm using PHP-Laravel. Not going to show the entire code, but give some hints about I did.

1.-First of all I created at the beggining of my code the command to create my results.txt file:

```
$resultsFile = Storage::put('results/results.txt', '');
```

2.- After processing info this is what I want to store: the resulting material and coordinates

```
$data_to_insert = [
                    'material' => 'how',
                    'coord_x' => $pixel_x,
                    'coord_y' => $pixel_y,
                ];
```

3.- I created this headers for my file:

```
$headers = [
             'orbit' => 'Vesta Test',
              'results' => []
];

$headers['results'] = $data_para_insertar;
file_put_contents('results.txt', json_encode($headers));
```

Well the problem comes when I try to get the info already stored:

```
$json_data = json_decode(Storage::get('results/results.txt'), true);
```

And try to merge my already results stored with my new result:

```
$results = array_merge($json_data['results'], $data_to_insert);
```

I just store the last register to my file:

```
{"orbit":"Vesta Test","results":{"material":"how","coord_x":946,"coord_y":963}}
```

I would like to store info on "results" in this way or similar

```
{
  "orbit":"Vesta Test",
  "results": [
              {"material":"how","coord_x":946,"coord_y":963}, 
              {"material":"how","coord_x":955,"coord_y":933},
              .....
   ]
}
```

All happens inside a for statement.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sound more like `$json_data['results'][] = $data_to_insert` than any need for the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the

```
$results = array_merge($json_data['results'], $data_to_insert);
```

you need to append the data to the results element, you can use

```
$json_data['results'][] = $data_to_insert;
```